# Object.Function (* is not a function)

Tags: javascript, function

How would I add a **function** after an **object**, without raising the error 'substr is not a function' ?

e.g.

```
    var country = {
        get: function() {
            return 'USA';
        },
        set: function(value) {
            
        }
    }

    console.log(country.substr(0, 2));
```

Comment: Your class has no constructor. It cant know if you mean `.get()`. Furthermore you can't instantiate a class in javascript without `new` keyword. So all you got there is a literal object definition, which is ok, but not reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use substr() in an object that only has .get() and .set(). susbtr() is a method of string, so you can chain it after .get() that actually returns a string:

```js
var country = {
        get: function() {
            return 'USA';
        },
        set: function(value) {
            
        }
    }

    console.log(country.get().substr(0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean add a function after an object. But if you want to log the substring of "USA", you are missing the call of the function in your log. Country is an object. It does not have any function `substring`. You have to define it first. You should call `get()` function to retrieve the value. It should be:

```
country.get().substr(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Country is an object, you can't use substring on an object.

You could do

```
country.get().subsring(0,2)
```

On another note, this is very un-javascript like code. Looks like you're trying todo OO programming in javascript.